# yielding items from NUL separated input in python

Tags: python, stream, nul

I have a situation in python where I need to loop items from a NUL separated stream given in a format similar to the output of `find /somewhere -print0`

- The stream is binary, items can consist of all bytes except NUL
- There is no way of knowing if the whole thing would fit in the available memory (assume the stream can be infinite).
- There is no way of knowing the length of the individual items (assume it could always be longer than `READ_SIZE` in my current solution below).

I feel like I'm missing something here, like `fd.readlines()` but for \0 instead of \n)

Here's what I currently use to tackle this:

```
READ_SIZE = 2**14
def readitems(fd):
    buffer = b''
    last = fd.read(READ_SIZE)
    while(last):
        x = last.split(b'\0')
        for i in range(len(x)-1):
            yield buffer + x[i]
            buffer = b''
        buffer += x[-1]
        last = fd.read(READ_SIZE)
```

If there's really no built-in method that I'm missing to do this, all faster and/or cleaner solutions are welcome.

Comment: The for loop won't fire if `last` does not contain a NUL and the while loop has to execute the last two lines regardless of the for loop firing.